# global try and catch block in qt

Tags: windows, qt, visual-c++

I am using Qt 4.8. Is there any way to have a global try and catch block for whole project.  Example, if my application has two .cpp files.  Is it possible way to catch exception across both .cpp files?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be warned that Qt doesn't play nice with exceptions. It was designed back in those days when exceptions were rather obscure feature of C++ so the use of exceptions was not generally considered a good practice for a whole bunch of implementation-related reasons.

Also be warned that as of Qt 5.7 the exception safety is not feature complete as the official [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html) currently tells:

> Preliminary warning: Exception safety is not feature complete! Common cases should work, but classes might still leak or even crash.

If you use signal-slot connections within your classes, it's best to handle exceptions inside the slots which may throw them. As of Qt 5.7 not doing so is [considered](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html#exceptions-in-client-code) undefined behaviour.

If you just want to do some cleanup and/or error logging on any occasionally uncaught exception, you can either wrap the entire `main()` contents into try/catch block as the previous answer suggests or alternatively you can [wrap the Qt's main event loop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html#recovering-from-exceptions) into such a block:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
...
try {
    app.exec();
}
catch (const std::exception &) {
    // clean up here, e.g. save the session
    // and close all config files.

    return 0; // exit the application
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put in brackets the entire contents of your `main()` function as follows::

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret = 0;

    try    
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);

        QWidget w;
        w.show();

        ret = a.exec();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        /* ... */
    }

    return ret;
}
```

See also: [`std::set_terminate()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/set_terminate/)